# Selecting data from html table and send it to database

Tags: php, html

I am new in using php and html. I have no idea to solve this issue  .I am trying to select fetching data from database and display it in html tables and after every row there is button to appoint. if i click that button the data in the row should be saved so i can use it to insert it on other table.
[In the select column i want to add a buttton after clicking the button the data in the row should be saved so i can use it later[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiGVr.png)

This is code for fetching data and displaying it in table.

```html
      <table style="background-color: white"　id="myTable">
        <tr>
          <th>
          <h1>
            Email
          </h1>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h1>
          Password
        </h1> 
        </th>
        <th>
          <h1>
            Select
          </h1>
        </th>
        </tr>
        <?php
   include 'db_connnection.php';
   $conn = OpenCon();


$sql1= "SELECT Email,Password from doctor_information ";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
   if($count < 0) {
            echo "No Records Available";
        }
        else{
         $array1=array();
         $count1=0;
          while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
             
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['Email']."<td>".$row['Password']."<td>"  ;
          
            ?>  


<?php


          }

}
?>


      </table>
```

It is not necessary to use a table if there is any other way to solve guide me.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you want to select have button & click on that it is inserted in to other table??

Comment: every row should have a button under select column after clicking that button  the data should be saved so i can use it to insert it to other table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**have an anchor tag like this:-**

```
    <?php

 include 'db_connnection.php';
   $conn = OpenCon();

$sql1= "SELECT * from doctor_information";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
   if($count < 0) {
            echo "No Records Available";
        }
        else{
         $array1=array();
         $count1=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {  ?>      
    <tr>
         <td> <?php echo $row['Email'];?>  </td>
         <td> <?php echo $row['Password'];?>   </td>
         <td><a href=insert.php?id="<?php echo $row['Email'];?>">INSERT DATA</a></td>    </tr>
<?php } }  ?>
```

**then maybe in your insert.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id']) {
        $Email = $_GET['id'];
        /* your code here to get Email from database, 
        and then insert code with that email
    }
?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224530/discussion-on-answer-by-kumar-selecting-data-from-html-table-and-send-it-to-data).